# how change the format of a column to allow for excel functions in reporting services

Tags: sql, excel, reporting-services

I have created a report in reporting services.When I download the report in an excel format I'm unable to to perform a SUM function on the columns.I first need to manually convert columns to number.Is there any way for me to do this on reporting services so that when I download the report I just sum the values without changing the column format.

I have thus far tried the following :

. Click on the cell, open the property window and update the Format property to be #,##0.00

Please could someone assist

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried to set in your tablix for cell Number format?

[image]

Comment: Which data you export in column where you want to make SUM? Can you bring for us example?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure if I understand your requirement correctly.

There is a long list of conversions you can do to fields in SSRS.

Suppose your field was `Fields!Number1.Value`

You can convert it as number as :

```
CLng(Fields!Number1.Value )
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your field to Integer or any other number format.

The value which returns from your database is returns as string and not Integer.

so when you export it to excel he present it as "General" field which is not a number format.

you need to specify that you want a field to be a "Number"

Follow this example:

I have created a report based on a dataset with the following fields:

- KPIID
- Name
- Grade

Now the specified that the `Grade` field needs to be an integer:

```
=CInt(Fields!KPI_Grade.Value)
```

Now see that in the excel i did a sum function on that field:

[image]